# Complex derivative involving exponents and natural log

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Find: $\frac{d}{dx} a^{x\ln x}$

I have tried several methods involving u-substitution etc, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I edited your question. Please check that it accurately reflects your intended meaning.

Comment: Any bounds on $a$?

Comment: no bounds on a, the edit is right, thanks!

Comment: All of your methods worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = a^{x \ln x}$. Then $\ln|y| = x \ln(x) \ln|a|$. Try using implicit differentiation from here.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d(a^{x\ln(x)})}{dx}=\dfrac{d(a^{x\ln(x)})}{d(x\ln(x))}\left(\ln(x)+1\right)=\ln(a)a^{x\ln(x)}\left(\ln(x)+1\right)$$
The last result is obtained by the logarithm laws and using the fact that $a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}$, and this holds $\forall a\neq0,a\neq a(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} a^{x \ln x} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \mathrm{e}^{x \ln x \ln a} \\
&= \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x \ln x \ln a \right)\mathrm{e}^{x \ln x \ln a} \\
&= \ln a \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x \ln x  \right)\mathrm{e}^{x \ln x \ln a} \\
&= \ln a \left( 1+ \ln x  \right)\mathrm{e}^{x \ln x \ln a} \\
&= \ln a \left( 1+ \ln x  \right)a^{x \ln x}
\end{align*}$$